# /bin/sh does not recognize hexadecimal escape sequences

Tags: bash, hex, escaping, sh

Why this happens on /bin/bash:

```
$ printf '%b' '\x90'
?
$
```

But this happens on /bin/sh:

```
$ printf '%b' '\x90'
\x90
$
```

Which difference between `/bin/bash` and `/bin/sh` and why first decodes hex and the second can't?

Comment: That depends on what shell is at `/bin/sh`, and as a consequence, what `printf` gets run. In Bash, it's a built-in; there's a binary that's part of the GNU Coreutils; dash (the `/bin/sh` of Ubuntu) has a `printf` built-in where `%b` means "Characters from the string argument are printed with backslash-escape sequences expanded", which might be what you see.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dash/+bug/1499473 <- because POSIX

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because escape sequences in `\xdd` form (where each `d` represents a hexadecimal digit) are a GNU extension and not available everywhere. But octals are widely supported (and [standardized](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html#tag_05)), so you can use:

```
printf '%b' '\0220'
```

Comment: How can I fast convert hex to octal using printf command?

Comment: @IvanNikolsky Try `perl -e 'printf "%03o\n", 0x90'`